# cannot recognize excel-VBA object after upgrade excel version

Tags: vba, excel, 32bit-64bit

after upgrade from excel 2010 32 bit to 64 bit, all the object i create in the new version cannot be recognize by other computer withe excel 2010 32 bit, i alrady tried to insert this:

```
If VBA7 = True Then
 ' 32 Bit API
Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
Else ' 64 bit API
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
End If
```

and it's not working.

plz help :)

Comment: What kind of help you do expect?

Comment: i want to able using the file in 32bit and 64bit excel

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct conditional compilation. It should look like this:

```
#If VBA7 Then
    ' 64 Bit API
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As LongPtr
    Private Declare PtrSafe Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As LongPtr, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#Else    ' 32 bit API
    Private Declare Function OpenProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, ByVal bInheritHandle As Long, ByVal dwProcessId As Long) As Long
    Private Declare Function GetExitCodeProcess Lib "kernel32" (ByVal hProcess As Long, lpExitCode As Long) As Long
#End If
```

Comment: i try it it's not working..., maby i not use it right? where i need to past this?

Comment: What do you mean by "it's not working"? What happens?

Comment: i i click on button so nothing happning, and if i Go into design mode and i click duble on the button so a new method creted was a new name

Comment: That code has nothing to do with buttons. It's WIndows API calls.

Comment: I can only answer what I see. It sounds like you simply haven't got the code hooked up to the button. If you're using ActiveX controls on worksheets, that can happen.

Comment: if you can i want to send you a two simple of xlsm file one is good and one is'nt if you have a office 2010 32 bit you see the problam to...

Comment: Add a file link here and I'll have a look.

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-QbJsV4U0IBZ0FQbTlVZHQwMmxFakdBWlB6TGt1X1RLTXln/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B-QbJsV4U0IBVHh1TWZWR0g2U052RDEwa0pSOHFEclVzcWlB/view?usp=sharing

Comment: need to change the kind from .txt to .xlcm